# Отображение/скрытие сетки листа одной кнопкой

Tags: excel, макросы, макрос

Имеются две кнопки и две соответствующие им команды.

По отдельности обе команды работают, но нужно сделать еще один макрос, чтобы состояние сетки менялось на противоположное (если есть, то чтобы убиралась; если нет, чтобы появлялась).

Понимаю, что это все делается нажатием парой клавиш, но с синтаксисм *VBA* я очень плохо знакома, поэтому рассчитываю на вашу помощь.

Скрин кода и сами команды прилагаю:

```
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
```

[image: фоточки команд]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub GridlinesVisibility()
    With ActiveWindow
        .DisplayGridlines = Not .DisplayGridlines
    End With
End Sub
```